# Clojure macro to check whether a function was called

Tags: clojure, macros, jvm

I started using Clojure a month ago, and for my integration tests I developed a little macro to check whether a function was called from an other function. The macro currently looks like this:

```
(defmacro called?
  [f val body]
  (let [flag (gensym `flag)]
    `(with-redefs-fn
      {~f (fn [& rest#] (def ~flag nil) ~val)}
      #(do
        (try
          (~body)
          (catch Throwable e#))
        (if (resolve '~flag)
          (bound? (resolve '~flag))
          false)))))
```

Usage:

```
user=> (called? #'clojure.core/println nil #(println "hey"))
true
user=> (called? #'clojure.core/println nil #(print "hey"))
heyfalse
```

Is there a way to call the original implementation without exploding the stack? I tried to do something like this in the first `let`, but this ends up with `ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Future`

```
    (let [flag (gensym `flag)
          orig-f# (deref f)] ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your goal is to write such macro yourself or you can use an existing library.

I would recommend [conjure](https://github.com/amitrathore/conjure) which not only allows you to ["spy" calls to a set of functions](https://github.com/amitrathore/conjure#instrumenting) but also verify what arguments have been passed to those functions:

```
(defn some-fn [n]
  (inc n))

(deftest test-instumenting
  (instrumenting [some-fn]
                 (is (= 43 (some-fn 42)))
                 (verify-called-once-with-args some-fn 42)))
```

conjure supports also mocking and stubbing for isolating your tests from external resources.

If you do want to implement it yourself, I would follow conjure's implementation which promotes some good practices.

Your macro should be only a thin syntax sugar layer using functions doing the main work. Create your wrapping function which will record if the original one has been called. By using a wrapping function and storing counts separately you can inspect it later, thus you can have your original functions to work unchanged and return real results.

```
(def call-counts (atom {}))

(defn instrumented-fn [original-fn]
  (let [wrapping-fn (fn this [& args]
                      (swap! call-counts
                             update-in
                             [original-fn]
                             inc)
                      (apply original-fn args))]
    (swap! call-counts assoc original-fn 0)
    wrapping-fn))

    (defn have-been-called?
      [original-fn]
      (pos? (@call-counts original-fn 0))

    (defn reset-counters! [] (reset! call-counts {}))
```

With your utility functions setup, you can add a thin syntax sugar layer with a macro:

```
(defmacro instrumenting [f & body]
  `(with-redefs [~f (instrumented-fn ~f)]
     ~@body))

(defmacro called? [f & body]
  `(let [origin-fn# ~f]
     (instrumenting ~f ~@body)
     (have-been-called? origin-fn#)))
```

Usage:

```
(defn my-fn [n] (inc n))

(have-been-called? my-fn)
;; => false

(instrumenting my-fn (dec 1))
;; => 0

(have-been-called? my-fn)
;; => false

(instrumenting my-fn (my-fn 1))
;; => 2

(have-been-called? my-fn)
;; => true

(reset-counters!)
(have-been-called? my-fn)
;; => false

(called? my-fn (dec 1))
;; => false

(called? my-fn (my-fn 1))
;; => true
```